# Removing brackets from python list

Tags: python

I am running an sql query that returns a result set that is stored in list x

```
('439FBFA0-B905-4C73-ABD4-3B1870AF1409', )
('425F9948-E1F3-45D3-9AC2-6A7DCA6F607E', )
```

here is my python code

```
x = []

cursor = conn.cursor()
label1 = cursor.execute("SELECT....")
for row in cursor:
    x.append(row)

for i in x:
    print(i)


s = x.replace(",","")

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

what is the best way to format the list? I want to remove the () and , and '
I thought replace would work in this case but i get error "'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"

The output i am looking for is

```
439FBFA0-B905-4C73-ABD4-3B1870AF1409
425F9948-E1F3-45D3-9AC2-6A7DCA6F607E
```

Comment: What about indexing into the list (or tuple as shown in the example)?  I.e.: `i[0]`

Comment: Here is a naive solution: `f = operator.itemgetter(0); [f(i) for i in x]`

Answer (score 0):

`('439FBFA0-B905-4C73-ABD4-3B1870AF1409', )` is a single row. To get the first column from it, you should simply index into it:

```
x = []

cursor = conn.cursor()
label1 = cursor.execute("SELECT....")
for row in cursor:
    x.append(row[0])
```

Or a bit cleaner:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
label1 = cursor.execute("SELECT....")
x = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Note that you can also access the column(s) by name, e.g. `row.column_name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in cursor:
```

cursors return a tuple for each row -- that's why you're seeing the parentheses & comma.  The easiest way to unpack it is

```
for (x,) in cursor:
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `join`:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in x))
```

`' '.join(row)` operates on one of your tuples and produces a string that simply joins the tuple elements with a `' '` (instead of the default `(element, )` formatting).  Doing this in a generator (`for row in x`) gives you a sequence of strings which you can then join together with `'\n'` to get the desired output.

This is essentially the same as doing:

```
for row in x:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

but the first form will be useful if you want to be able to do something with this string other than print it.  :)